# Selecting Arrival and exit time using time picker in android

Tags: java, android, xml, timepicker

Here am selecting arrival and exit time using imageview with help of TimePickerFragment, DialogFragment.
My question is how to select the exit time..When am selecting exit time it will show in the arrival time text box only. How to solve this problem help me.

Here code for arrival and exit time 
Am using two text box and two image view button.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
EditText arrtime,exittime;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public void selectArrivalTime(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");
}
public void selectExitTime(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");

}
    public void populateSetArrTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        arrtime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        arrtime.setText(+hourOfDay+":"+minute);

    }
    public void populateSetExitTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        exittime= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        exittime.setText(+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }
    public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
             int hour =  calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                        DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            populateSetArrTime(hourOfDay, minute);
        }
        public void onTimeSet1(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            populateSetExitTime(hourOfDay, minute);
        }
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

This is my XML layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
    android:text="Arrival time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="Exit time" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="time" />

<EditText
  android:id="@+id/editText2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
  android:clickable="false"
  android:ems="10"
  android:focusable="false"
  android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
  android:inputType="time" >

</EditText>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/selectarrtime"
    android:onClick="selectArrivalTime"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/selectexittime"
    android:onClick="selectExitTime"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If select a arrival time i will shows time in my arrival edit text box and also if i select a exit time it will shows the time in same arrival edit text box not displaying in my exit edit text box how to slove this pls help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't used anything (Like Button) to select the time how your application will get to know that you want to select time now.

Comment: with the help of this code am selecting arrival time but when i select a exit time it will shows in arrival time edit text box only why?

Answer (score 0):

```
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
EditText arrtime,exittime;
static type="";    //changed

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton b1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); //changed from here
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setTime("arrival");
        }
    });
    ImageButton b2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            setTime("exit");
        }
    });  ///to here
}
public void setTime(String type) {   //function changed
    MainActivity.type=type;
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "TimePicker");
}    
public void populateTime(int hourOfDay, int minute) {  //function changed
    if(type.equals("arrival") {
        arrtime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        arrtime.setText(+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }
    else if(type.equals("exit") {
        arrtime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        exittime.setText(+hourOfDay+":"+minute);
    }
}
public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
         int hour =  calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        populateTime(hourOfDay, minute);  //changed
    }        
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Also delete line android:onClick line from both the ImageButtons in your xml file